# Delimiter issue with Scraping a JSON file from a LAN connection and parsing with json.loads()

Tags: python, regex, json, python-2.7

I've scraped a json from a LAN connection but I am unable to parse it through json.loads.

I'm trying to get all of the html from within the text lines, as you can see at the bottom.

I get the following error: `ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 9 column 39 (char 222)`

```
import json
import urllib2
##json_data = urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.1.221:39285/set/json/sec", timeout=30).read()
json_data = """
    {
        "line_type":"Test",
        "title":"Test",
        "timestamp":"201310201628",
        "line": [
                                            { 
                "id":2,
                "text": "<span class=\"prefix\">\n                                Result            <\/span>\n            \n"                } ,                                             { 
                "id":1,
                "text": "<span class=\"prefix\">\n                                Result            <\/span>\n            \n"                }                     ]
    }
"""

s = json.loads(r'{}'.format(json_data))
print s['line']
```

I want to be able to print: `<span class=\"prefix\">\n                                Testing            <\/span>\n            \n` **and** `<span class=\"prefix\">\n                                Test            <\/span>\n            \n`

Any help would be much appreciated

**I should of mentioned I'm looking for a regex or a workaround...**

Answer (score 1):

Try to print `json_data`. That's what you'll see:

```
    {
        "line_type":"Test",
        "title":"Test",
        "timestamp":"201310201628",
        "line": [
                                            { 
                "id":2,
                "text": "<span class="prefix">
                                Testing            <\/span>

"                } ,                                             { 
                "id":1,
                "text": "<span class="prefix">
                                Test            <\/span>

"                }                     ]
    }
```

Apparently, it's not a valid JSON. You have some mix-ups with escaping:

1. Quotes must be escaped as `\\"`: the first backslash is the escaping for a Python string, and the second one is the escaping for a JSON string literal.
2. You can't have literal newlines in JSON string literals; you have to write them as `\n`, therefore in a Python string they should be written as `\\n`.
3. (not sure) you do not need to escape forward slashes, or is `<\/span>` actually a desired result?

(Note: you can get rid of one level of escaping if you use `r""" """` string literals.)

After these changes, the JSON can be loaded:

```
>>> s = """
...     {
...         "line_type":"Test",
...         "title":"Test",
...         "timestamp":"201310201628",
...         "line": [
...                                             { 
...                 "id":2,
...                 "text": "<span class=\\"prefix\\">\\n                                Testing            </span>\\n            \\n"                } ,                                             { 
...                 "id":1,
...                 "text": "<span class=\\"prefix\\">\\n                                Test            </span>\\n            \\n"                }                     ]
...     }
... """
>>> 
>>> json.loads(s)
{'line': [{'text': '<span class="prefix">\n                                Testing            </span>\n            \n', 'id': 2}, {'text': '<span class="prefix">\n                                Test            </span>\n            \n', 'id': 1}], 'timestamp': '201310201628', 'title': 'Test', 'line_type': 'Test'}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't change the json, I should of mentioned I'm trying to make a regex for this data.

Comment: See the note. If you add ``r`` before the triple quote in your question, it becomes valid too.

Comment: Well, it works for me with your exact example. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is your friend.  If you copy the actual text between """ """ this is valid JSON.  As Bogdan says, your mistake is not escaping the \.  If you've copy/pasted the data from another source, you're possibly getting confused with the escapes.  A single \ is valid escape for JSON, but a double \\ is required to escape a slash in a Python string.  By search/replacing \ to \\, your original code works for me too.

Comment: Basically, I'm scraping a  LAN based website so lets say im using urllib2 to to set `jsondata` so i an unable to put the r before the variable.

Comment: You do not put ``r`` before a variable, you put it before a literal. If you already have your json in a variable, you should not need even that (and your example in the question has nothing to do with the problem you are having).

Comment: It scrapes the json, which automatically comes out as shown in my example. I don't get to put the literal in...

Comment: @Bogdan, See my edited example in my first post. It shows my issue a bit better I think.